# MySQL inserting a column into a variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm working on a project that needs to prevent double username inserted in a database my code looks like this:

```
    Command = New MySqlCommand("Select * From userscanner", Connection)
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
            dr = Command.ExecuteReader
            With dr
                .Read()
                Dim check As String = .Item(1)
                .Close()
                If check = txtbox_username.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Username Already Taken")
                    Exit Sub
```

My problem is it only gets 1 column or is there any other way to prevent double username in my database?

I need all column in my username column. I'm using VB and MySQL.

Comment: Why don't directly query for the entered username in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ask your database if a particular user name exists or not. 
This could be done with a [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) clause

```
 Dim sqlText = "SELECT 1 FROM userscanner WHERE username = @name"
 Using Command = New MySqlCommand(sqlText, Connection)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbox_username.Text 
    Dim result = Command.ExecuteScalar()
    if result IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Username Already Taken")
    End If
End Using
```

Here I assume that your database table named `userscanner` has a field named `username` (the field retrieved by your code with Item(1)) where you store the user names. Adding a WHERE condition and a simple return of 1 if there is a record allows to use the simple [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns the value 1 if there is a matching record to your textbox value or Nothing if there is no record

Comment: Thanks Your answer is really helpful but I make my own way based on your answer and I guess mine is a much simpler way. I'll post it and please let me know if it has disadvanteges

Comment: @OrdizImbano your's isn't simpler at all, use parameter's as Steve has shown to do. Also wrap your command in using to ensure it is getting disposed and such. Just use his answer...

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to the question on my own.

```
 Command = New MySqlCommand("Select * From userscanner WHERE Username = '" & txtbox_username.Text & "'", Connection)
 Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
 dr = Command.ExecuteReader
 dr.Read()
 dr.Close()

 If dr.HasRows Then
    MsgBox("Username Already Taken")
```

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: The answer from @Steve has some advantages.  What would happen if somebody entered the following user name: "';DROP TABLE userscanner;"???

Comment: NO, this is the wrong way to make a query. Never use string concatenations. Parameterized queries solve the problem of Sql Injection ([Here a funny but instructive example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)) and what if your user name textbox contains a single quote? (for example `O'Hare` causes a syntax error here) . Then a disposable object like the command and the connection should be disposed after usage (the using statement does this) finally the ExecuteNonQuery has no meaning for a SELECT query.